# javascript foreach return results containing name

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

I have the below javascript which returns the name1 value for each item.

```
var data = [{"name1": "aaa", "name2":"bbb", "other":"ccc"},{"name1": "ddd", "name2":"eee", "other":"fff"}];

function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  contName = element.name1;
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + contName);
}

data.forEach(logArrayElements);

//returns below in console
a[0] = aaa 
a[1] = ddd
```

I want to return all values containing name for each item.
I could do this by adding in

```
contName2 = element.name2;
console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + contName);
```

However I don't want to list it out as I will have a different amount of 'names' on different occasions.
I know when searching for a string I can do the below, but can't work out how to work something similar into what I have above?

```
var myName = "name2";
console.log(myName.indexOf("name") > -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then walk each of the objects in the array like so:

```
var myArray = [
    {"name1": "aaa", "name2":"bbb", "other":"ccc"},
    {"name1": "ddd", "name2":"eee", "other":"fff"}
];

myArray.filter(function(row){

    for( key in row ){

        if( key.indexOf('name') === 0 ){ // only matches keys **starting** with "name"

            console.log( 'a[' + key + '] = ' + row[key] );

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: That would also get a key named `briname` (I've just invented that word).

Comment: He said "containing name", but he probably meant what you're saying. Fixed, thx :)

Comment: Looks good thanks, is it possible to add it in as a variable for reuse? eg I tried to replace name with a var called myName = "name"; see fiddle, but it doesn't return the results like you example does? http://jsfiddle.net/08qxxm50/

Comment: @ak85 your fiddle doesn't work because you added myFilter as a parameter to array.filter, so it'll get overwritten in the scope of the filter. Since you're declaring myFilter outside of the function, it will be available inside array.filter. See http://jsfiddle.net/o6ovrnft/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

I would loop through your object's keys to find those who start with 'name' :

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  for(var i in element){
      if(i.indexOf('name') === 0){
          contName = element[i];
          console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + contName);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late in the game, but I just wanted to add another alternative to the mix using lodash.

```js
var data = [{
  "name1": "aaa",
  "name2": "bbb",
  "other": "ccc"
}, {
  "name1": "ddd",
  "name2": "eee",
  "other": "fff"
}];

function getFields(data, expression) {
  var re = new RegExp(expression, "i");
  
  return _.reduce(data, function(result, object) {
    return _.union(result, _.reduce(object, function(list, value, key) {
        if (re.test(key)) {
          return _.union(list, [value]);
        } else {
          return list;
        }
    }, []));
  }, []);
}

alert(getFields(data, '^name'));
alert(getFields(data, '^other'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

This function above returns all the names found as an array. The function accepts two arguments: the array to be searched and a regular expression to match the key names of the values to be returned.